# Surface and volume from Graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

Suppose we have a graph as follows

```
Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {3, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 3}, {8, 9}, 
{9, 5}}, VertexCoordinates -> {{-0.9782750307906163, -0.9782750308127439, 0}, {0,-0.7667734500991006, 0}, {0, 0, 0.6523279164959646}, {-0.7667734511111024, 0, 0}, {0, 0.7667725657729597, 0}, {-0.9782750520965101, 0.9782740437039809, 0}, {0.978274043438298, -0.97827505235892, 0}, {0.7667725648559436, 0, 0}, {0.9782740605839738, 0.9782740597848466, 0}}]
```

[image]

I would like to

I. Get the "surface" that it generates, that is, to fill with plane patches the empty spaces and

II. Obtain the volume under it (the boundary is forced to be on the "plane", i.e all the outer points are at the same height)

Is there a direct way to do it ?

Comment: Look into `MeshRegion` / `BoundaryMeshRegion` instead of `Graph`.

Comment: There is a slight problem that the quads are non-planar, so you could have trouble if you don't retriangulate the mesh.

Comment: As was mentioned earlier, faces with more than three edges are not guaranteed to be planar, and there are multiple ways to fill the same nonplanar face with planar patches, so in general there is not a unique surface that such a graph will generate.

Comment: @DanielMcDonald Understood. I would like to know if Mathematica has *any* simple way to obtain *an* answer with the input as shown in the question. The reason I don't care too much about uniqueness is that I will use it will graphs containing many vertices, so in that limit the filling "method" is not very important.

Comment: @user:69211 An answer is below.

Comment: @IAmANaïf no they are not co-planar. Look at the middle vertex from the points provided in the question's `VertexCoordinates`. Your answer flattens this vertex to the plane, but you don't have the raised bump in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

```
chm = ConcaveHullMesh[GraphEmbedding[g], BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5]]]
```

[image]

```
Volume @ chm
```

> ```
> 0.652428
> ```

```
Show[chm, g]
```

[image]

**Update:** Alternative ways to construct surfaces from `g`:

```
g1 = EdgeAdd[g, {3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 7, 3 <-> 9}];

mr1 = MeshRegion[GraphEmbedding[g], 
  Polygon[VertexList /@ FindCycle[g1, 3, All]], 
  MeshCellStyle -> 
    {2 -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.3]], 
    {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Blue], 
    {1, 3 | 4 | 9 | 14} -> Opacity[0]}, 
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {0 -> ({Opacity[1], Hue[.6, .6, 1], 
        Sphere[#, 0.05]} &)}]
```

[image]

```
Area @ mr1
```

> ```
> 3.97784
> ```

```
g2 = EdgeAdd[g, {2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 8, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 8}]; 

mr2 = MeshRegion[GraphEmbedding[g], 
  Polygon[VertexList /@ FindCycle[g2, 3, All]], 
  MeshCellStyle -> 
   {2 -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.3]], 
   {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Blue], 
   {1, 1 | 6 | 10 | 12} -> Opacity[0]},
  MeshCellShapeFunction -> {0 -> ({Opacity[1], Hue[.6, .6, 1], 
        Sphere[#, 0.05]} &)}]
```

[image]

```
Area @ mr2
3.6642
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to construct such surface manually.

```
pts = {{-0.9782750307906163, -0.9782750308127439, 
    0}, {0, -0.7667734500991006, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0.6523279164959646}, {-0.7667734511111024, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0.7667725657729597, 0}, {-0.9782750520965101, 0.9782740437039809, 
    0}, {0.978274043438298, -0.97827505235892, 
    0}, {0.7667725648559436, 0, 0}, {0.9782740605839738, 
    0.9782740597848466, 0}};
HighlightMesh[Point[pts], Labeled[0, "Index"]]
surf = MeshRegion[pts, 
   Polygon[{{3, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 8}, {3, 8, 5}, {3, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {7,
       8, 2}, {9, 5, 8}, {6, 4, 5}}]];
HighlightMesh[surf, Labeled[0, "Index"]]
```

[image]

```
surf // Area
```

> `3.6642`

Comment: @cvgmtAs I understood the request, the volume below the surface and above the Z=0 is what was requested. The area was not requested. Due to the wording of the request, 10 distinct volumes may have been meant.